# which files need wcf web service deployment on iis

Tags: wcf

What files do i need to put in iis directory when deploying wcf web service in iis adding as site?

For example:
Is it just dll from bin and service contract? 
Does example.cs code files need to be copied in iis directory too?

Comment: I guess that you have tried something and it doesn't work. Show what you have tried and what doesn't work. You generally just have to deploy the binaries and the `.svc` file.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Yes i have tried to add site, that contains my .svc,  .cs, .edmx and bin folder with web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you have in your service.

Usually, the **bin folder**, the **configuration file** and **.svc file**, if it exists.
But it's better let Visual Studio  handle this. Right click over your service project and then "Publish". Visual Studio will copy everything you need to deploy to a folder.

Comment: thanks, i have to copy manually i am not allowed to publish from visual studio for some reason. So if i was to do it manually. Which files do i need copy?

Comment: But Publish is like a simple copy command, if you configure to copy to a local folder, it's very simple... anyway, as I described in answer, you need to copy the bin folder, the config file and any file with svc extension if exists.